# Jacoco - How to check which lines are missing coverage

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I am using jacoco for Test coverage verification in a Java Library created with Gradle. I have set the verification rule to limit minimum coverage to 1.0 (100%). I have a few classes in my code which are not meeting the criteria. based on the unit-tests that I have written, I don't think I am missing any line of code.

on those lines, I was wondering if there is a was to make jacoco print out which lines are not getting covered by unit tests during the build process?

currently jacoco causes a build failure reporting the coverage ration for each files that didn't meet the bar but it does not provide any information on specific lines that were not covered.

Comment: jacoco generates a `.html` file with a very detailed report

Comment: Hi Eugene, it there a default location for this html file?

Comment: I found this https://docs.diffblue.com/knowledge-base/cli/coverage-report/#how-to-generate-a-jacoco-report-gradle Ill try it and update the answer if it works. Thanks for pointing in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure My Gradle-Groovy project to start generating Jacoco coverage reports by doing the following:

added `jacoco` plugin to `buildscript` in `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

adding a custom configuration:

```
jacocoTestReport {
 dependsOn test
}
```

chaining `jacocoTestReport` to your `test` task

```
test {
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport 
}
```

This ensures, report is always generated after tests run.

**Note: if you have added both jacoco and java plugin, reports are automatically generated and stored at `$buildDir/reports/jacoco/test`** in such a scenario, you can skip above steps.